# End of week of current week in Snowflakes

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I have a date column called Close_Date.

How do i get the Close_date to only give me date for end of the current week?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Last_Day function. There is a parameter WEEK_START that affects which day is the last day of the week. Here is the link below:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/last_day.html

```
ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_START = 6;
SELECT LAST_DAY(current_date, 'week');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SQL in your tables DDL and It will give you the Week ending date as Saturday of the Current week. For this you don't need to change session parameters every time.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2021-01-01') AS DATE,
IFF(DAYOFWEEK(DATE) = 0,DATEADD(DAY,6,DATE),DATEADD(DAY,-1,LAST_DAY(DATE,'week'))) AS Week_Ending_Dt
```

Change DATE as per your need.